# Need a more efficient solution than looping

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a spreadsheet that tracks work in progress as it moves through steps of a manufacturing process.

Each step of the process has a column with the total parts moved to each stage. To the left of this column is a column for number of parts moved to the stage (parts move through a few at a time).

My scrpit then takes the values in the "add" column, adds them to the "total" column, then reset the "add" column to "".

Here's the code:

```
function addColumns() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
    // sheet is the first worksheet in the spreadsheet

    for (var i=4; i<500; i++ ) {
        if(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()>0){ //Only run if order number not empty
            //Breakout Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,6);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,7);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            //CNC Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,8);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,9);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            //CutSand Column 
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,10);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,11);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            //Lasered Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,12);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,13);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            //To Finishing Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,14);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,15);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            // Defective Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,17);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,18);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
            //Etsy Column
            var add = sheet.getRange(i,20);
            var total = sheet.getRange(i,21);
            total.setValue(total.getValue() + add.getValue());
            add.setValue("");
        }
        if(sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue()<1){i=500} //Once you find a blank order exit the loop
    }
}
```

My code as written does accomplish this; it does exactly what I need. The problem is that since the code is accessing the spreadsheet on each loop it takes almost a full second per cell to run, and with 7 steps per order it can take minutes at a time to run through with lots of orders...

This is a pretty simple mathematical task, so there has to be a more efficient way of doing it, I just haven't been able to find the right keywords to describe what I need to do.

I am quite happy to learn whatever needs to be done, just need to know what direction to head.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do something like this: (not tested)

```
function addColumns() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; // Refers to the first worksheet in the spreadsheet
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Acquires all values of the sheet
    for (var i = 3; i < data.length; i++) { // Loop over every row
        if (data[i][0].length > 0) { // Check if first column has a value

            // Breakout
            sheet.getRange(i+1,7).setValue(parseFloat(data[i][6]) + parseFloat(data[i][5]));
            sheet.getRange(i+1,6).clear();

            // Repeat code above for other columns
        }
    }
}
```

This code acquires all the data from the sheet instead of looping over a fixed amount of 500 rows. Assuming that your data starts at row 4, I've implemented this in the code above as well.

Variable `data` acquires all the data at one moment instead of trying to fetch values of every range (cell) all the time. I expect that this will save your script quite some time.

Because we acquire the data at once, the script sees the value as a string. Before we calculate the new value of the total column, we parse the value as a float (a number with decimals).

The code above is not tested as I don't have a sheet ready in the same format as you do but I think the logic is clear and if it doesn't work I suppose you should be able to adjust it to work for your sheet.